# how to reference NSTableView inside NSView Class (Cocoa)?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I m trying to implement a mac application, basically I have a NSTableView inside a NSView.
I implemented a drag & drop of multiple files feature on the NSView, now I want to update NSTableView with the files names just dropped.

So I need to reference NSTableView in my NSView and try reloadData to reload tableview.

I have tried initialised tableview controller in NSView and it seems not working?

```
MyTableController *testController = [[MyTableController alloc] init];

    testController.nsMutaryOfDataObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i ++) {
        NSString * zStr1 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d",(i + 1) * 10];
        NSString * zStr2 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d",((i + 1) * 100) + 2];
        NSString * zStr3 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d",((i + 1) * 1000) + 3];
        MyDataObject * zDataObject = [[MyDataObject alloc]initWithString1:zStr1
                                                               andString2:zStr2
                                                               andString3:zStr3];
        [testController.nsMutaryOfDataObject addObject:zDataObject];
    } // end for

    [testController.idTableView setHeaderView:nil];
    [testController.idTableView reloadData];
```

Xib file as below:
[image]
Anyone can help me out?

Comment: The tableview can be a drag destination on its own. It would be the responder rather than a simple containing view around its ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

A tableview has TWO different aspects: the view (presentation of data; drag and drop) and the datasource (an array combined with an array controller).
Usually a tableview leads a life on its own, independent from the view it is positioned in. So concentrate yourself first on the datasource-aspect and second on the drag-and-drop-aspect.

1. "TableView reload" simply means load the assigned array again.
2. For the data structure in your array a model is strongly recommended.
3. The names of the different parts in your model are bound to the columns in your table.
4. The array is the datasource to your tableview.
5. Use an array controller.
6. Your fileNames must be in the array, organized in the manner of the model...
7. Because a tableview is always part (subview) of an NSScrollView, assure that your really have selected the tableview itself.

In the documentation are fairly good samples for working with tableviews, with and without bindings, also "TableViewLinks" handling URLs...

Your code is missing the basic methods for a tableview to work, so start from scratch with a sample.

Comment: I have a tableview controller class and data class with delegate and datasource set. Then I have another NSView class which connects to the NSView where NSTableview embeds. Initially the drag and drop method was implemented in this NSView class, that is why I want to find a way to reference the NSTableview

Answer (score 0):

Sounds, as if the TV is working correctly
and
you have the fileNames available in the NSView class
and
don't want to implement the drag and drop functionality also in the class for the TV.

Then you could use a notification that is sent from the NSView-class to the TV-class with the fileNames-data attached. After receiving in the tv-class the fileNames could be used/added to the array. I once have created such a solution, it works perfect.

It also assures encapsulation of the classes.